# Can list comprehensions use multiple variables?

Tags: python, for-loop, list-comprehension

```
cluster = [z for z, val in enumerate(distances) if val == min(distances)]
```

I've been trying to find a way to rewrite this without list comprehension, and have so far come up with this:

```
for val in enumerate(distances):
    if val == min(distances):
        cluster.append(val)
```

I know this can't be correct because I have completely left out `z`. But I don't understand how this format of list comprehension works, where `val` is used instead of `z` in the second half of the list comprehension.

Comment: The `for` loop should look like the one in the comprehension.

Comment: Try `print(val)` in your for loop. Its a tuple and is the same as `(z, val)` in the list coprehension.

Comment: As an aside, calculate `min(distance)` once before the loop. No need to repeat that step.

Answer (score 2):

It's more straightforward than you think. The 'value' in your list comprehension should go at the innermost part of the `for` loop. The `for` should go on the outside, and the condition(s) afterwards should go in the middle.

```
cluster = [z for z, val in enumerate(distances) if val==min(distances)]
```

```
cluster = []
for z, val in enumerate(distances):
    if val == min(distances):
        cluster.append(z)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code in regular for loops would be:

```py
cluster = []
for z, val in enumerate(distances):
    if val == min(distances):
        cluster.append(z)
        #or cluster += [z]
```

The list comprehension is simply this `for` loop condensed into a single line.

Comment: `cluster += [z]`.

Answer (score 1):

The `for` loop should look exactly like the one in the comprehension. In general a comprehension like this:

```
<target> = [<expression> for <loop-var> in <iterable> if <condition>]
```

breaks down as follows:

```
<target> = []
for <loop-var> in <iterable>:
    if <condition>:
        <target>.append(<expression>)
```

In your case, you have

```
<target> = cluster
<loop-var> = z, val
<iterable> = enumerate(distances)
<condition> = val == min(distances)
<expression> = z
```

Notice that the loop variable is a tuple that you've unpacked into two separate names. You do that correctly in the comprehension but not in the loop:

```
clusters = []
for z, val in enumerate(distances):
    if val == min(distances):
        cluster.append(val)
```

By making the loop variable just `val`, you are comparing a tuple like `(0, 100)` to a value of `min(distances)`, like `100`, and always getting `False` of course. If you ever magically got `True`, your resulting list would look like `[(0, 100)]` rather than `[100]`.

Keep in mind that computing `min(distances)` at every iteration actually makes your algorithm run in `O(n^2)` time rather than the `O(n)` time it should be running in. Since the condition `val == min(distances)` is evaluated at every iteration in both the loop and the comprehension, I recommend factoring the computation of the minimum out and just making the comparison:

```
min_dist = min(distances)  # compute once
clusters = []
for z, val in enumerate(distances):
    if val == min_dist:    # no more iterating through the whole list
        cluster.append(val)
```